# How to to convert my curl method to work in my javascript script?

Tags: javascript, curl, spotlight-dbpedia

Beginner in javascript,
I'm looking for ways to convert my curl method to work in my javascript script.

Here is my curl method:

```
curl -X GET "http://model.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate?text=beyonce" -H "accept: text/html"
```

My test with ajax (doesn't work):

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://model.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate?text=beyonce"
})
```

Comment: Is there PHP to the question?

Comment: with ajax you have the additional issue of CORS to think about and the example code above features `data: { confidence:"0.60"}` but that doesn't appear in the curl code

Comment: Also, the curls sends the accept header, whereas the ajax request does not, and seems to return XML from the looks of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AJAX call is missing the `accept` header.

Once you add this in, it seems to work. Please see the example below:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://model.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate?text=beyonce",
    data: { confidence: "0.60" },
    headers: {"accept" : "text/html"}
}).done((res) => $("#res").append(res));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [***fetch API***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) over this jquery ajax method you're using. It's quite [supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)

```
fetch("http://model.dbpedia-spotlight.org/en/annotate?text=beyonce").then(response => response.text())
```

If you consider using it, I'd also recommend learning how to deal with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in case you don't know!